# Randomly re-partition 1Dimensional List to 2Dimensional

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote a solution Please look at the my approach is correct? There is a better solution?

```
List<Tuple<object, object, object>> OneDimensionalLists = new List<Tuple<object, object, object>>();
List<Tuple<object, object, object>[]> TwoDimensionalLists = new List<Tuple<object, object, object>[]>();

int i1 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < OneDimensionalLists.Count; i++)
{
    var random = new Random(seed);
    int next = random.Next(10, 30);
    TwoDimensionalLists.Add(new Tuple<object, object, object>[next]);
    for (int j = 0; j < next; j++)
    {
        if (OneDimensionalLists.Count == i1)
            goto go;

        TwoDimensionalLists[i][j] = OneDimensionalLists[i1++];
    }
}
go:
```

Comment: _I wrote a solution_ - well, this isn't a good description of your code and the`goto` this is a no-go ;-D

Comment: Could kindly explain what you are trying to achieve with this code e.g  the output, input etc?

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < OneDimensionalLists.Count; i++)
> {
>     var random = new Random(seed);
>     int next = random.Next(10, 30);
>     ...
> ```

Have you checked the value of `next` on the various iterations? I can't see `seed` changing anywhere in this code. Assuming it remains the same, `random.Next()` will return the same value each time. Unless this is intentional, create the `Random(seed)` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you declare and assign a variable in a single statement, if you are not going to assign it as `null`, use the `var` keyword instead of the type name.

```
List<Tuple<object, object, object>> oneDimensionalList = new List<Tuple<object, object, object>>();
```

could become

```
var oneDimensionalList = new List<Tuple<object, object, object>>();
```

which is far simpler.

The odds that someone will be randomly working with `Tuple<object, object, object>` are pretty slim in my opinion, so you should perhaps consider changing your method(?) to accept a `List<T>` if not a `ICollection<T>` or even an `IEnumerable<T>` instead.

Speaking of "method," it seems that this code should be one. It effectively takes an input and produces an output, so why not isolate it to be its own piece of code that you can call wherever you want? You could also get rid of that `goto` statement in favor of a proper `return`.

It would look something like this:

```
public static List<Tuple<object, object, object>[]> MakeTwoDimensional(
    List<Tuple<object, object, object>> oneDimensionalList)
{
    var twoDimensionalList = new List<Tuple<object, object, object>[]>();

    // Somehow transform 'oneDimensionalList` into `twoDimensionalList`

    return twoDimensionalList;
}
```

Your conditional statement using the `i1` variable reads very oddly. Granted, I normally wouldn't be using a loop over a collection with a randomly generated number as the conditional, but maybe that's just me.

Outside of the code itself, I don't understand what "problem" you are trying to solve. I don't see how this type of transformation would be useful. In your example, the code will actually do nothing, as the first list is initialized empty and nothing is added to it.